# Linear model selection - Subset, Forward

Tags: model-selection, linear

We use 2**p model variations in order to define best model in subset selection. In contrary, we use 1 + p(p+1)/2 models in forward selection. But in the book it states,

*"Since we perform guided search over model space, we utilize substantially more than 1 + p(p+1)/2 models in forward selection"*

What does it imply?

Source -- Introduction to Statistical Learning, Chapter 6.1.2, Page 209, footnotes.

Any recommendations appreciated.

Comment: What is "the book"??

Comment: Introduction to Statistical Learning, Chapter 6.1.2, Page 209, footnotes.

Comment: Those claims seem contradictory.  The latter apparently comes from the book.  Where does the initial claim come from?

Comment: The same book as well. Chapter 6.1.1 - 6.1.2,page 205-209. The book states the first claim and then, in the footnote, it states the latter one.